# SSRS Multiple Select Parameter Fails with Single Parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a multi-select parameter setup that works fine with multiple parameters.  However, when a single parameter is chosen it fails:

[image]

Working with multiple parameters selected for reviewer name:

[image]

How do I setup and reference the parameter to work with a single selection?

Query:

```
    SELECT        EPERMIT_APPLICATION.WORK_NUMBER, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.APP_TYPE, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.STATUS, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.SUBMIT_DATE, EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.CREATE_DATE AS ASSIGN_DATE, 
                         EPERMIT_APPLICATION.APPROVAL_DATE, EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.REVIEWER, EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.FNAME + ' ' + EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.LNAME AS REVIEWER_NAME, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.BUCKET, 
                         EPERMIT_APPLICATION.BUCKET_PENDING, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.STATUS_DATE, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.RFMI_DATE, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.EXTENSION_DATE, EPERMIT_APPLICATION.APPROVAL_NUMBER, 
                         EPERMIT_APPLICATION.OP_APPROVAL_DATE, EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.CONTACT_ID
FROM            EPERMIT_APPLICATION LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         EPERMIT_EPEOPLE ON EPERMIT_APPLICATION.WORK_NUMBER = EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.WORK_NUMBER
WHERE        ((EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.FNAME + ' ' + EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.LNAME) IN (@RevName)) AND (EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.CREATE_DATE >= @StartDate) AND (EPERMIT_EPEOPLE.CREATE_DATE <= CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate)) AND 
                         (EPERMIT_APPLICATION.STATUS IN (@AppStatus))
ORDER BY ASSIGN_DATE
```

Comment: Are you trying to run your query on an Oracle db?`

Comment: The error has to do with the Oracle database being a linked server. It's having trouble translating the query through because of the two different versions of SQL involved. Can you connect to the Oracle data source directly? If not, you may have to pursue a workaround like using the `INSTR` function with joined parameter values instead of an `IN` statement.